# Empty Trash - Nautilus consumes 6.7gb of RAM Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit

Tags: 13.10, nautilus, git

I was building a directory from the command prompt and by accident initialized the entire home directory instead of the folder that I wanted, is there a way to undo this? The readme.md is in the trash along with some folder that must have been created as I have no clue what it represents the name is all goofy.

I try to delete the files from trash and natulis soon ends up consuming 7gb of my 8gb of ram. So basically is there a way to de-initialize this directory?

Thank you,

**Edit**

I did use the following command `rm -rf .git` and the home directory was no longer a git repo, but I still cannot delete the files I have in my trash, my system immediately become unusable for awhile until I either hold the power button down or use the system monitor to end the nautilus process, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the files in Trash from the command line also. Those files are stored in the `~/.local/share/Trash/` directory. The `~/.local/share/Trash/files/` directory contains the actual files, the `~/.local/share/Trash/info/` directory contains the metadata about the removed files. Just empty these 2 directories.

Comment: when I try to delete a folder I use `rmdir` on it and it tells me that it is not empty, so I go to the folder on the command line and type `ls` to see what is in it and nothing opens up? Are there hidden files since it was a git repo? Also I can see one file in a directory and I use rm to get rid of it and it tells me it does not exist...

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator If the files were hidden before deletion then they are still hidden in that folder, because their name still starts with a dot. If you want to see them just type `ls -A`. For that un-deletable file I think you should run an `fsck` on that partition. It likely got corrupted when you forcefully shutdown your system while it was operating on those files.

Comment: could be because I also tried `rm -f foldername` and nothing is happening

Comment: found a lot of hidden .git folders and files what a pain